# What's wrong here? Connection failure?

Tags: pluggable-transports, network-configuration

When I try to connect to Tor, says:

> tor establish a network connection failure Connecting relay directory
>   failed (lack of pluggable transport type bridge)

[image]

Comment: sorry, but no one will be able to diagnose a problem from just this information. could you set your locale to English to capture a screenshot, then reset it afterwards?